# Error with RPI update

Tags: apt

```
Unpacking linux-image-5.10.0-23-arm64 (5.10.179-2) over (5.10.179-1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-5.10.0-23-arm64_5.10.179-2_arm64.deb (--unpack):
 unable to make backup link of './boot/System.map-5.10.0-23-arm64' before installing new version: Operation not permitted
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-5.10.0-23-arm64_5.10.179-2_arm64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Any ideas what I can do to fix this? I have checked a few different tutorials and none I have seen so far has worked.

Comment: What statement did lead to this `unpacking...` ? Probably you did forget to add `sudo ` ?

Comment: What OS & release are you using?   Those don't appear to be on-topic or Ubuntu kernels (instead I see Debian) so you've polluted your sources most likely. What are you running?

Comment: Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and *official* flavors of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.   *Your packages appear to come from http://security.debian.org/pool/updates/main/l/linux/*

Comment: I used sudo, i always use sudo. if i've polluted sources, how do I fix?